# TypeScript this: new () => T parameter with protected constructor

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am trying to force users to provide all necessary parameters when instantiating subclasses without requiring a `constructor(params: Partial<Subclass>)` in each subclass. The following system works if a public constructor is available, but not when it is protected.

Base class:

```
abstract class Message {
    messageType: number = 0;

    (((protected))) constructor() {}

    static construct<T>(this: new () => T, params: Omit<T, 'messageType'>): T {
        return Object.assign(new this(), params);
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
class MessageExample extends Message {
    field!: number;
}
```

Instantiation:

```
MessageExample.construct({field: 123});
```

Is there a way to allow `MessageExample` to be passed to `construct()` with a protected constructor (and perhaps prevent abstract classes from being passed)?